# Retrieving binary back to image and from database and save into a folder using WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, image, linq

I have successfully converted image to binary and saved it into the database using linq to sql WPF and now i want to retrieve it back to image format and save it to a specific folder in computer.

i have read many blogs and articles which retrieves the image binary from database and then shows it into the PictureBox, what i want to do is to select the image and save it to a specific folder using linq to sql.

code which i have tried so far for uploading an image:

```
private void Browse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.DefaultExt = ".jpg";
            ofd.Filter = "Image File (.jpg) | *.jpg";

            Nullable<bool> result = ofd.ShowDialog();

            if(result == true)
            {
                string fileName = ofd.FileName;
                _txtFileName.Text = fileName;
            }
        }

        private void Upload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using(ImageDataContext db=new ImageDataContext())
            {
                image_data img = new image_data();

                img.image = ConverImageToBinary(_txtFileName.Text);

                try
                {
                    db.image_datas.InsertOnSubmit(img);
                    db.SubmitChanges();

                    MessageBox.Show("Picture Upload Successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
                }

                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        public static byte[] ConverImageToBinary(string convertedImage)
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(convertedImage, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

                byte[] image = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

                br.Close();

                fs.Close();

                return image;
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;//MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of your code to read the image is way to complex, you're opening it as a Stream and reading well, all bytes. There's a method that does exactly that so you can replace your whole ConverImageToBinary method with

```
img.image = File.ReadAllBytes(_txtFileName.Text);
```

Also you never "converted" anything to anything, an image is just an array of bytes on disk, you've read it, saved it to the database, if you read it back and save it back (using this time File.WriteAllBytes) it will work just fine, so

IF you want to write to the disk then just save the image back to disk as such:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"d:\myfile.bmp",img.Image.ToArray()) ;
```

And make sure you change the extention to match your file type (so bmp for a bitmap jpg for a jpeg etc)

Comment: Please note that the question is about WPF. Although mentioned in the question, there is no PictureBox in WPF. You would instead load a BitmapImage from a local file URI or from a MemoryStream, and put it in an Image control. There are of course also plenty of answers on StackOverflow that show how to do that exactly.

Comment: Really depends on what he means, he could be hosting a picturebox (winform) within wpf althought i doubt it

Comment: @RonanThibaudau.... I have used "File.WriteAllBytes(@"d:\", img.Image);" but it returns exception even thou after converting it to int and binary still it throws exception "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.Binary' to type 'System.IConvertible"

Comment: @Clemens....dear actually my problem was to save the image back to folder yes i know that IMAGE control is used to display image in WPF...i appreciate you help..

Comment: Well yea because System.Data.Linq.Binary is NOT a byte array, however we can't know what it is since you didn't tell us, apparently it's a binary that's a Linq specific datatype (btw when you're asking about linq, tell us WHICH linq, linq is just a contract but for example linq to sql and linq to entities are very diferent). In your code just replace img.Image with img.Image.ToArray() and you should be fine

Comment: Also File.WriteAllBytes could never work the way you state it, you're just telling it to save to d:\ that's a folder not a file, it needs a filename!

Comment: @RonanThibaudau...it worked but now its returning "Access to the path 'd:\' is denied."

Comment: Save it elsewhere than to the top of d, it was just an example but typically you can't write to the top level of a disk without running as administrator (or launch your program as administrator, and before you come back to tell us you're an administrator on your computer, this does NOT mean the program is running as administrator, you'd need to actively shift right click it and select run as administrator). But the easiest way is to save the file well, anywhere where you're allowed to write (your documents, the desktop, or any folder you create etc)

Comment: @RonanThibaudau....thanks it worked actually i did not provide the name for image that why it threw me this exception....Thanks Alot..Marked as answe :)